# How to draw an object onto sfml window when a function is called?

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a character sprite moving across the screen and when I press 'a' I want the program to draw the sword sprite onto the screen and make the sword go away when I am not pressing 'a'. Currently I have an attack function that sets a showweapon boolean as true, and a if statement that is supposed to draw the weapon onto the screen but nothing happens. Is there a better way to do this?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Character.h"
#include "Projectile.h"
#include "Weapon.h"

using namespace std;

bool scroll = false;

Character player("/Users/danielrailic/Desktop/Xcode /NewGame/ExternalLibs/Player.png");
Weapon woodsword("/Users/danielrailic/Desktop/Xcode /NewGame/ExternalLibs/WoodSword.png");

bool showweapon;

int main() {
    // insert code here...
    int windowWidth = 5000;
    int windowHeight = 5000;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight ), "Awesome Game" );


    sf::Texture dungeon;
    dungeon.loadFromFile("/Users/danielrailic/Desktop/Xcode /NewGame/ExternalLibs/DungeonBack.png");
    sf::Sprite backround;
    backround.setTexture(dungeon);

    while (window.isOpen()){

        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)){
            player.left();
            }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)){
            player.right();
            }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)){
            player.forward();
            }
        if (sf:: Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)){
            player.backward();
            }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LShift))
        {
            player.Highspeed();
        }
        else{
            player.Lowspeed();
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)){
            woodsword.attack();
        }
        window.clear(sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
        window.draw(backround);
        if(showweapon == true){
            window.draw(woodsword.getSprite());
            window.display();
            cout << "Hello";
        }
        window.draw(player.getSprite());
        window.display();
        window.setFramerateLimit(70);

        }
    }
```

I am also not receiving the "hello" message

weapon.h

```
class Weapon : Character{
    bool showweapon;
public:
    sf::Texture texture;
    //Constructor
    Weapon(string wep)
    : Character(wep){
        texture.loadFromFile(wep);
        showweapon = false;
    }
    sf::Sprite getSprite() {
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 100, 100));
        sprite.setPosition(x_pos, y_pos);
        return sprite;
    }

    //Methods
    void attack();

};

void Weapon::attack(){
    showweapon = true;
}
```

If you need to see anything else let me know. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The code you claim is your main.cpp won't compile, can you post the actual code, `if(showweapon == true)` is obviously wrong but is that just because its been incorrectly copied? Is the `if` statement body executing, have you figured out what's actually failing ,i.e. does `window.draw(woodsword.getSprite());` do anything, is the sprite object valid etc...?

Comment: The `showweapon` in your main and in your woodsword class are 2 different variables. Try using `if (woodsword.showweapon == true)`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the if statement to : if (woodsword.showweapon == true) and I also made a sheath method in the weapon class that sets showweapon false so the sword goes away when I don't press 'a'. Thanks for everyones help.